# What should I use as a config/settings file with emacs prelude?

Tags: emacs, emacs-prelude

I would like to add a hook, so that each time I open a new file, projectile is enabled. However, I don't know where to add it so that emacs will read it. Any hints?

Comment: `Projectile` is globally enabled by default in Prelude. Otherwise - @phils is totally correct.

Answer (score 10):

This must *surely* be in Prelude's documentation? If not, I suggest you write to the author to suggest that it be added.

I note the following in its `init.el` file:

```el
(defvar prelude-personal-dir (concat prelude-dir "personal/")
  "Users of Emacs Prelude are encouraged to keep their personal configuration
changes in this directory. All Emacs Lisp files there are loaded automatically
by Prelude.")
```

Therefore you should create a `personal` sub-directory if it doesn't already exist, and create any `*.el` filename you like in that directory, for your own customisations.